# how to create array with explode text in php

Tags: php, arrays, explode

After all I'm sorry for my English.

I'm writing a script in **PHP** and I encountered a small problem.

The idea is to create an array per line of text and replace the fourth value with a string representing the status.

I have a line of text e.g.
**2022,33422,0,1,0,22**

With a single line it works to create the array, but with multiple lines it creates an unexpected result.

Example:

**2022,33422,0,1,0,22**

**2024,3232,01,1,04,298762**

```
        $myArray = explode(',', $uploadServer);
        $status = array(0  => "Unprocessed",
                 1  => "Processing",
                 2  => "Download aborted because the file became too big.",
                 3  => "Download aborted because the file downloaded too long.",
                 4  => "Download finished. Uploading to RapidShare.",
                 5  => "Upload to RapidShare finished. Job finished.",
                 7  => "Upload failed 3 times for unknown reasons. Job aborted.",
                 8  => "Upload failed because the file is black listed.",
                 9  => "Download failed for unknown reasons.",
                 11 => "Enqueued for later processing because this account already downloads 5 files at the same time.");



        foreach ($myArray as $valor) {
              if(array_key_exists($valor[3],$status)) {

                    return $passer[] = $status[$valor[3]];

              } else {

                    return FALSE;

              }
        }
```

The result of **$myArray** is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2022
    [1] => 33422
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 22
)
```

But I need this final array

```
Array
(
[0]=>array(
          [0] => 2022
          [1] => 33422
          [2] => 0
          [3] => Processing
          [4] => 0
          [5] => 22
          )

[1]=>array(
           [0] => 2022
           [1] => 33422
           [2] => 0
           [3] => Processing
           [4] => 0
           [5] => 22
          )
)
```

Any idea?
thanks

Comment: Possible approach: Do two splits: 1) Explode by line ends in your multiline text - you'll get an array of lines.  2) Explode each line like you did and add the result to your summary array.  When done, revise the logic of handling #3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: So you have a string with a linebreak in it. This linebreak is an invisible character (\n). First split your string on every linebreak. Then loop through this array. split the strings on every comma and change the value with index 3:

```
$myArray = explode("\n", $uploadServer);

$status = array(0  => "Unprocessed",
             1  => "Processing",
             2  => "Download aborted because the file became too big.",
             3  => "Download aborted because the file downloaded too long.",
             4  => "Download finished. Uploading to RapidShare.",
             5  => "Upload to RapidShare finished. Job finished.",
             7  => "Upload failed 3 times for unknown reasons. Job aborted.",
             8  => "Upload failed because the file is black listed.",
             9  => "Download failed for unknown reasons.",
             11 => "Enqueued for later processing because this account already downloads 5 files at the same time.");

$passer = array(); //create array to fill
foreach( $myArray as $valor ) { //loop through lines
   if( !empty($valor) ) { // check for empty line
     $tmp = explode(',', $valor);  //make array of strings
     if(array_key_exists($tmp[3],$status)) {  //check value [3]
       $tmp[3] = $status[$tmp[3]];
     }     
     $passer[] = $tmp;   //append array to parent array
  } 
}
```

Comment: first I need to make the array of the two texts.
After obtaining the array need to replace the text.

Comment: perfect, thanks. now only i study for remove the final empty array

Comment: @aleksanderhaugas the empty array is probably caused by a line break at the end of the string. Just check if the line is empty before creating and appending another array. (updated code above)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you are overthinking the solution.

```
   foreach ($myArray as $valor) { 
          if(isset($status[$valor[3]])) {  # this checks if there is a status with that index/key
                 return $passer[] = $status[$valor[3]]; 
           } else { 
                 return FALSE; 
           } 
    }
```

Comment: parser [] does not do anything just to used to create a loop